# Segue to navigation controller goes black

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a segue from a button to a navigation controller that a master view controller is embedded in (I used the ["Your Second iOS App" tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple Developer).  The problem was that whenever I clicked the button, I would get a totally black screen with just a navigation bar.  There isn't any code involved.  Would anyone happen to know how I could fix this?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any code involved?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.  It was because the split view controller was also pointing to the master view controller, so it had 2 segues pointing to it.